# How to change the specific string throughout all git message commits?

Tags: git, version-control, github, rebase, git-rewrite-history

I want to grep and change specific string throughout all messages that are pushed to Github. Is it possible? How?
I know how to change last message bye `git commit --amend` but I want to change all message of all commits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`git-filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) with it's `--msg-filter` option, e.g.:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/git-svn.*$//g"' -- --all
```

Note that this will change pretty much *all* your commit ids in your repo, and so everyone who works on your project will thus need to do a fresh clone.

See this blog post for some more discussion:

http://mm0hai.net/blog/2011/03/10/rewriting-git-commit-message-history.html

Note that the above command only executes against your local copy, and you need to push to GitHub in order to get your updates reflected there...

Step-by-step

First clone a **fresh** copy of your repo, using the `--mirror` flag:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/my-repo.git
```

This is a bare repo, which means your normal files won't be visible, but it **is** a full copy of the Git database of your repository, and at this point you should make a backup of it to ensure you don't lose anything.

Now you can run `git-filter-branch` to fix your commit messages:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/git-svn.*$//g"' -- --all
```

Once you're happy with the updated state of your repo, push it back up (note that because your clone command used the `--mirror` flag, this push will update **all** refs on your remote server):

```
$ git push
```

At this point, you're ready for everyone- including yourself -to ditch their old copies of the repo and do fresh clones of the nice, new pristine data.

...I'm compelled to point out that [The BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is often much better than `git-filter-branch` for cleaning up Git history, but in this case just `git-filter-branch` sounds perfect for your needs.

Comment: Thank roberto, I have changed all of "is" to "was" in my commit history (My english is too bad :D ). why Github doesn't show the actual strings? see here: https://github.com/khajavi/Design-Patterns/tree/master/Behavioural and here https://github.com/khajavi/Design-Patterns/commits/master/Behavioural compare the. why they are different???!

Comment: @Khajavi that was probably just a browser refresh issue, the commit messages on both pages matched when I checked them just now - for instance, the latest commit message is "Behavioural's readme was added." for both.