# Censoring commit history

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, revision-history

Is there any way to censor certain worDs from git commit messages from the commit history? Not from files or actual code, but from the commit messages themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) tool's message callback to replace words in your commit messages

```
git-filter-repo --message-callback 'return re.sub(b"word",b"<redacted>",message)'
```

This will replace `word` with `<redacted>` in all your commit messages.

`filter-repo` tool is not bundled with git, so you need to install it [separately](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it).

Using `filter-branch` as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874218/10155936):

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "s/word/<redacted>/g"' -- --all
```

Comment: I had a feeling you were thinking about filter-repo. I presented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309

Comment: Anything that can be done only with what is bundled with git?

Comment: @nowi [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is an option but it is not safe as mentioned in the docs under **WARNING** section [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_description) . Also see VonC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

Comment: @nowi if you are worried about installation, one easy option is to use `pip3`. Just do `pip3 install git-filter-repo` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installation-via-pip)

Comment: @nowi See warning section [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning) in git docs which also mentions about `git-filter-repo`

Comment: I do not have pyhton setup for `pip3` commands. Could you help me write a command using `filter-branch` safely? What exactly does that specific `git-filter-repo` command end up boiling to that I can use?

Comment: Is it case sensitive?

Comment: I will wait @VonC 's reply before doing it.

Comment: @nowi I believe it is generally case sensitive if you are referring to `sed `

Comment: @nowi The sed command is case sensitive. The command looks safe, but  I would recommend executing it on a fresh clone, for testing.

Comment: Isn't working for me. It first complained about msg-filter and then I realized it was missing the `--`. Now it is complaining that `fatal: bad revision 's/word/<redacted>/g''`

Comment: @nowi It should work now, I missed the `--` for `msg-filter` option

Comment: @nowi , If you are running this command in Windows CMD, it won't work because `sed` is not available by default for Windows except if you have installed GNU tools for Windows like CoreUtils, you can run it in git bash though